# How to autoupdate chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager

i need help getting webdrivermanager to autoupdate chromedriver. I've read the forums on updating this and they dont make any sense. I'm trying to do this with python 3.x but i keep running into errors. Here is my current code

```
import webdrivermanager
webdrivermanager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager.get_compatible_version()
```

it comes back with the error TypeError: _get_browser_version() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0):

**webdriver-auto-update**

There is a package in PyPI and GitHub called `webdriver-auto-update`. It will detect the driver version on your computer and download the latest chrome driver version/release automatically.

**Installation:**

Make sure you have Python installed in your system.
Run the following in your terminal to install:

`pip install webdriver-auto-update`

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_auto_update import check_driver


# Pass in the folder used for storing/downloading chromedriver
check_driver('folder/path/of/your/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Reference link:

https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-auto-update/
https://github.com/competencytestlvl/webdriver_auto_update

Answer (score 0):

> it comes back with the error TypeError: _get_browser_version() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>
> ```py
> import webdrivermanager
> webdrivermanager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager.get_compatible_version()
> ```

Here is a missed class `()` after `ChromeDriverManager`

The working code will be

```py
import webdrivermanager
webdrivermanager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager().get_compatible_version()
```